# .Net Console.WriteLine and System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(); not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, console, console.writeline

In my .Net MVC 5 project all of my Console.WriteLine statements have simultaneously stopped working. I am in Debug mode (not release) and so is my output window (pics for proof):

[image]

[image]

However when I run this code for example:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Phone1,Phone2,Division_District,OrgNumber,DateOfTest,DateOfExposure,NumberOfExposed,Notes,PathToFile")] Case_Log case_Log, HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing print");
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Case_Log_Docs/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Created the folder.");
            }

            if (PostedFile != null)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
                case_Log.PathToFile = fileName;
                PostedFile.SaveAs(path + fileName);
                ViewBag.Message += string.Format("<b>{0}</b> uploaded.<br />", fileName);
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    db.Case_Log.Add(case_Log);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine("The save worked.");
                }
                catch(DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(case_Log);
        }
```

None of the writeline statements trigger. Nor do they trigger anywhere else in the app. Previously I was only using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` but when it stopped working I tried `Console.WriteLine()` which actually did work 1 time but then never again.

Any ideas on how I could get this to work again? It is difficult to debug without them.

Comment: Yikes! If you're trying to log things, look into using [Serilog](https://serilog.net/), [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) or some other logging library. Both of them can output to the console or myriad other configurable locations.

Comment: hmm.. I'm not certain.. try calling `Console.OpenStandardOutput();` at `Program.Main` (which I believe exists in that app)

Comment: @ColeDOT: Put breakpoint on your `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` line and check that `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners` collection contains the `System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener`. It provides the default output tracing.